# Select Consecutive ID's in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table like this.

```
ID              Installment ID       DateDue 
------------------------------------------------------------    
000000000008    29                   2017-03-15 00:00:00.000 
000000000008    30                   2017-04-15 00:00:00.000 
000000000008    32                   2017-06-15 00:00:00.000 
000000000008    33                   2017-07-15 00:00:00.000 
000000000008    34                   2017-08-15 00:00:00.000
```

What I need is a select query that returns data on only 3 successful consecutive installments (so in this example 32,33,34), between a specific date range.

Assuming failed are populated in another table (31).

So I would want a return of serial number, installment ID.

Comment: 6,6,7 -- Consecutive?

Comment: Sorry, rectified. 6,7,8

Comment: what it should return if you have 3,4,6,7,8,9?

Comment: with a defined date between x and x, max of 3 records with ID, and Installment ID.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `LEAD` and `LAG` function available in SqlServer 2012 and do like this.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/ZBC87590)

```
;WITH cte1 AS
(
SELECT * , datepart(m,(lead(datedue) OVER(ORDER BY installmentid)))-DATEPART(m,datedue) nowtonext
         ,DATEPART(m,datedue)-datepart(m,(lag(datedue) OVER(ORDER BY installmentid))) prevtonow
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY installmentid) as rn
FROM YourTable
),
cte2 AS
(
SELECT rn,id,installmentid,datedue,nowtonext,prevtonow
        ,lead(prevtonow) OVER(ORDER BY rn) AS prev
        ,lag(nowtonext) OVER(ORDER BY rn) AS nxt
FROM cte1
)

SELECT id,installmentid,datedue 
FROM cte1 
WHERE rn BETWEEN (SELECT rn-1 FROM cte2 WHERE nowtonext = 1 AND prevtonow=1 AND prev=1 AND nxt=1)
            and (SELECT rn+1 FROM cte2 WHERE nowtonext = 1 AND prevtonow=1 AND prev=1 AND nxt=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query in order to return islands of consecutive records having consecutive `InstallmentID` numbers:

```
;WITH CTE_Group AS (
   SELECT ID,
          InstallmentID,
          DateDue,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID 
                             ORDER BY DateDue) - InstallmentID AS grp
   FROM mytable
   WHERE DateDue BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
), CTE_Count AS (
   SELECT ID, InstallmentID, DateDue,
          COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, grp) AS cnt
   FROM CTE_Group
)
SELECT ID, InstallmentID, DateDue
FROM CTE_Count
WHERE cnt >= 3
```

If you want only 3 records out of each island, then you can use `ROW_NUMBER` with a `PARTITION BY cnt` clause in order to extract the first 3 records of the island.

**Explanation:** The query of the first CTE, `CTE_Group`, uses the 'difference between row numbers trick' in order to identify consecutive records having consecutive `InstallmentID` numbers within a predefined date range (`@startDate - @endDate`).

**Output from `CTE_Group`**:

```
ID  InstallmentID   DateDue     grp
------------------------------------
8   29              2017-03-15  -28
8   30              2017-04-15  -28
8   32              2017-06-15  -29
8   33              2017-07-15  -29
8   34              2017-08-15  -29
```

The query of the second CTE, `CTE_Count`, uses `COUNT() OVER()` in order to count the population of each island.

**Output from `CTE_Count`**:

```
ID  InstallmentID   DateDue     Cnt
-----------------------------------
8   32              2017-06-15  3
8   33              2017-07-15  3
8   34              2017-08-15  3
8   29              2017-03-15  2
8   30              2017-04-15  2
```

Using `CTE_Count` we can easily filter out records that belong to islands having a population of `2` or less.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/TJO86837)